# "mode" command not working in windows 8.1

Tags: php, windows, serial-port, windows-8.1, gsm

I am trying to send an SMS from PHP via a connected GSM mobile (NOKIA 5530).  For this I've tried using the PHP serial library but it's not working.

It is giving me following error messages:

> Warning: Unable to set baud rate: 'mode' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. in E:\xampp\home\MapMyWay\phpSerial.php on line 265
>
> Warning: Unable to open the device in E:\xampp\home\MapMyWay\phpSerial.php on line 173
>
> Warning: Device must be opened in E:\xampp\htdocs\home\phpSerial.php on line 661
>
> Warning: Device must be opened to read it in E:\xampp\htdocs\home\phpSerial.php on line 576

When I tried to run the `mode com4:/status` in the command prompt, it says "mode is not recognizable".

Comment: Could you just confirm whether `C:\Windows\System32\mode.com` or the equivalent exists on your system?